# Transform carousel items with different sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made this carousel in plain HTML, CSS and JavaScript to cycle through some images.
Some of the images however have different aspect ratios, which causes them to transform differently from the other items.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cumxvthw/12/)

I had initially set the translation values to percentages, and thought that shifting to vw and vh values would solve the problem, but the improvement was marginal and the problem still persists.
Is there a way in which I can have the item always centered in their absolute position?

Here are the following code snippets:

```js
function carousel() {
    const slider = document.querySelector(".carousel_items");
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel_item");
    const button = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

    let current = 0;
    let prev = current > 0 ? current - 1 : slides.length - 1;
    let prev1 = prev - 1;
    let prev2 = prev1 - 1;
    let prev3 = prev2 - 1;
    let next = current < slides.length - 1 ? current + 1 : 0;
    let next1 = next + 1;
    let next2 = next + 2;
    let next3 = next + 3;
    let next4 = next + 4;

    const update = () => {
        slides.forEach(it => {
            it.classList.remove("active");
            it.classList.remove("prev", "one");
            it.classList.remove("prev", "two");
            it.classList.remove("prev", "three");
            it.classList.remove("prev");
            it.classList.remove("next");
            it.classList.remove("next", "one");
            it.classList.remove("next", "two");
            it.classList.remove("next", "three");
            it.classList.remove("next", "four");
        });

        slides[current].classList.add("active");
        slides[prev1].classList.add("prev", "one");
        slides[prev2].classList.add("prev", "two");
        slides[prev3].classList.add("prev", "three");
        slides[prev].classList.add("prev");
        slides[next].classList.add("next");
        slides[next1].classList.add("next", "one");
        slides[next2].classList.add("next", "two");
        slides[next3].classList.add("next", "three");
        slides[next4].classList.add("next", "four");
    }

    const moveLeft = document.getElementsByClassName('left');
    console.log(moveLeft)
    const moveRight = document.getElementsByClassName(".next");
    console.log(moveRight)

    for (let i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
        button[i].addEventListener("click", () => i == 0 ? gotoPrev() : gotoNext());
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < moveLeft.length; i++) {
        moveLeft[i].addEventListener("click", () => gotoNext());
    }


    const gotoPrev = () => current > 0 ? gotoNum(current - 1) : gotoNum(slides.length - 1);
    const gotoNext = () => current < slides.length - 1 ? gotoNum(current + 1) : gotoNum(0);

    const gotoNum = number => {
        current = number;
        prev = current > 0 ? current - 1 : slides.length - 1;
        prev1 = prev > 0 ? prev - 1 : slides.length - 1;
        prev2 = prev1 > 0 ? prev1 - 1 : slides.length - 1;
        prev3 = prev2 > 0 ? prev2 - 1 : slides.length - 1;
        next = current < slides.length - 1 ? current + 1 : 0;
        next1 = next < slides.length - 1 ? next + 1 : 0;
        next2 = next1 < slides.length - 1 ? next1 + 1 : 0;
        next3 = next2 < slides.length - 1 ? next2 + 1 : 0;
        next4 = next3 < slides.length - 1 ? next3 + 1 : 0;

        update();
    }

    update();
}

carousel();
```

```css
:root {
  --extended_bg: 0;
  --item-border-size: 4px;
  --corner-offset: 60px;
}

.carousel {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.carousel_items {
  height: 70vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
}

.carousel_items .carousel_item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: auto;
  height: 35vh;
  max-width: 30vw;
  object-fit: contain;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  clip-path: polygon(
    var(--corner-offset) 0%,
    100% 0,
    100% calc(100% - var(--corner-offset)),
    calc(100% - var(--corner-offset)) 100%,
    0 100%,
    0% calc(0% + var(--corner-offset))
  );
  isolation: isolate;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  line-height: 0;
}

.carousel_items .carousel_item::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}

.carousel_items .carousel_item::before {
  background: whitesmoke;
  z-index: 3;
  clip-path: polygon(
    0% 0%,
    0% 100%,
    var(--item-border-size) 100%,
    var(--item-border-size) calc(0% + calc(0% + var(--corner-offset) + 1px)),
    calc(0% + calc(0% + var(--corner-offset) + 1px)) var(--item-border-size),
    calc(100% - var(--item-border-size)) var(--item-border-size),
    calc(100% - var(--item-border-size)) calc(100% - var(--corner-offset) - 1px),
    calc(100% - var(--corner-offset) - 1px) calc(100% - var(--item-border-size)),
    0 calc(100% - var(--item-border-size)),
    0 100%,
    100% 100%,
    100% 0%
  );
}

.carousel_item .img {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 300px;
}
#item_6 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 550px;
}

.carousel_item.active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 99;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 105px -35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.carousel_item.prev {
  z-index: 98;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transform: translate(-19vw, -23vh) scale(0.8);
}

.carousel_item.next {
  z-index: 98;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transform: translate(2vw, -23vh) scale(0.8);
}

.carousel_item.next.one {
  z-index: 97;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transform: translate(8vw, -28vh) scale(0.75);
}

.carousel_item.prev.one {
  z-index: 97;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transform: translate(-23vw, -28vh) scale(0.75);
}

.carousel_item.next.two {
  z-index: 96;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transform: translate(10vw, -38vh) scale(0.65);
}

.carousel_item.prev.two {
  z-index: 96;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transform: translate(-23vw, -38vh) scale(0.65);
}

.carousel_item.next.three {
  z-index: 95;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transform: translate(4vw, -50vh) scale(0.55);
}

.carousel_item.prev.three {
  z-index: 95;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transform: translate(-18vw, -50vh) scale(0.55);
}

.carousel_item.next.four {
  z-index: 94;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: translate(-6vw, -53vh) scale(0.45);
}

.carousel_items .button-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 47%;
  width: 11vw;
  z-index: 100;
}

.button-container .button {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.75;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.button-container .button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -99;
}

.button-container .button:nth-child(2) {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="carousel">
      <div class="carousel_items">
        <div id='item_1' class="carousel_item active">
          <div class="img"></div>
        </div>
        <div id='item_2' class="carousel_item next">
          <div class="img"></div>
        </div>
        <div id='item_3' class="carousel_item">
          <div class="img"></div>
        </div>
        <div id='item_4' class="carousel_item">
          <div class="img"></div>
        </div>
        <div id='item_5' class="carousel_item">
          <div class="img"></div>
        </div>
        <div id='item_6' class="carousel_item">
          <div class="img"></div>
        </div>
        <div id='item_7' class="carousel_item">
          <div class="img"></div>
        </div>
        <div id='item_8' class="carousel_item">
          <div class="img"></div>
        </div>
        <div id='item_9' class="carousel_item">
          <div class="img"></div>
        </div>
        <div id='item_10' class="carousel_item prev">
          <div class="img"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="button-container">
          <div class="button">
            <i class=""></i>
          </div>
          <div class="button">
            <i class=""></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```